# Cloud9 Python: getting Flask module not found on Run action

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, flask, cloud9-ide

I started an empty Ubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) workspace on **cloud9**. Python 2.7.6 was there by default. I installed **python-pip** and **python-virtualenv** (using apt-get).

Having created the smallest possible **Flask** application I've faced a problem: I get an import error if I press ide's **Run** button:

[image: Cloud9FlaskProblem]

**Update**

The same problem here: https://community.c9.io/t/not-able-to-run-python-file-which-has-a-import-statement-for-flask-installed-via-virtualenv-py/6151

If I run the application from terminal by issuing **`python app.py`** then everything's fine:

[image]

Virtual environment is activated.

**`pip list`** shows

> ...
>
> Flask (0.12) - it's there.
>
> ...

**`which python`** shows

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/env/bin/python

What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: Check your workspace settings. There is a setting somewhere about which Python version to use and you might have to flick that the other way. Once you do that, try running with the runner again and that may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If running from the terminal after activating the environment works fine maybe you could include the command to activate the virtual environment from within the script, for example:

```
import os
os.system("source env/bin/activate")
import flask
```

you may need to use an absolute path for the environment but that should be easy enough to find

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help. I recreated the workspace using the **Python** template. Created v/env. Checked if I run pip from the environment, got positive on that. Problem persisted. I found out that by default pip and virtualenv, even wrapper for it, are already installed (at least for Python workspace template). On my home machine I'm running Zesty and I'm able to run things like gunicorn without problems (on c9 it's somewhat problematic due to flask not being recognized).